# Implemeting search funcionality on iterated data from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

So I created a sandbox of the thing I am working on https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hellman-h9yqg Basically here I am fetching data from an API, I have iterated the data in Book Component, I have also Link in component/HoverBooks which is taking me to the details page/Book. I have iterated the data in the Search Component. I am trying to implement Search functionality of bookNames, which when they pressed are pushing me to the DetailsPage/Book. If something is wrong with sandbox please leave a comment. Thanks

Comment: `TypeError
Cannot read property 'book' of undefined`

Comment: Can you please copy your code over into runnable StackOverflow code format?

Comment: @ControlAltDel there is like 8 components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a bit of trouble in the way you prepare the data for your filter function. The key piece of code is

```
function filterBooks(book) {
    console.log(book);
    if (!searchValue.length) return true;
    return book.bookName?.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data)
        .map((key) => data[key])
        .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
        .filter(filterBooks)
        .map((book) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div
                onClick={() => {
                  history.push("/book/id", { book });
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                {book.bookName}{" "}
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-pine-pbchq?file=/src/Book.js

Fixed!

Comment: Thank you Kind Sir, but I was wondering how would I manage to achieve so books are showing only when I start to type the names. Right now they are all displayed

Comment: Oh, in that case you would have to change `return true` to `return false` in the second line of `filterBooks()`

Comment: @ diego92sigma6 If it not to much to ask what is the difference between my filter function, and yours because as far as I have seen both are doing the job?

Comment: @ diego92sigma6  Last one I swear, what is the opposite of prevent default. Now when I press on the book and it pushes me to the details page in the search, the search values do not reset

Comment: You can add setSearchValue('') on onClick if you want to show all the books again.

Comment: I changed some spelling in your filter function but it literally does the same besides that `return false` we discussed

Comment: @ diego92sigma6 Thank you for the help